# Multiple server processes on a Multihomed machine with one process bound to 0.0.0.0

Tags: networking, routing, multi-homed

I develop a data broker service that repeats individual device data onto multihomed IP addresses on a single interface. Each repeat server is a separate process bound to a specific TCP IP and port (e.g. 10.0.34.50:29950 and 10.0.34.51:29950). Also on this sever is another process, which binds to 0.0.0.0:29950 as well.

On Ubuntu, client connections to the individual Multi-Homed IP's route successfully to those repeat server processes. On Red Hat 8.8, the process bound to 0.0.0.0:29950 accepts all incoming connection.

Clients should be able to connect to the individual Multi-Homed IP's when they are specified, and not always connect to the process bound to 0.0.0.0 (listen on all interfaces/subnets). As this seems to work on Ubuntu and not Red Hat. There's something I'm missing.

There is a configuration difference between these OS's that I haven't found yet.

I've been digging into tunables such as
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_filter
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route

I'm wondering whether this requires policy based routing? I'll be trying that as well.

Comment: welcome, what is your business environment or relationship in here? because I don't see any. More over 0.0.0.0 matches any address and will block the port that is bound to. what research has been already done here?

Comment: To know what proper routing happened, you'd have to provide full examples of what did or didn't work, with the way to reproduce it, along the system's routes (which might differ between RHEL 8.8 and Ubuntu 22.04). Without proper additional socket options using setsockopt(2) (that you did not mention), you can't bind twice to the same port (no mention of port either...) when addresses overlap. Then the protocol does matter. UDP can behave differently than TCP in a multi-homed environment (specifically replies can get wrong if UDP setup is too simple).

Comment: Sorry, first question. Read through the asking a good question docs. Will update more after further troubleshooting. The edits detail what's been tried so far

Comment: Again: this doesn't work by default. There's a collision between binding to 0.0.0.0:29950 and any other x.y.z.t:29950 unless specific options are used. So as you don't know about such options (which I made sure to not explicitly mention to wait for you to describe their use), your problem is different. At a guess: something is running in a container.

Answer (score 2):

`0.0.0.0` is the *unspecified address*. When binding a socket it means *this host*, ie. on any interface or with any IP address.

Accordingly, that behavior you describe seems to be correct. You need to configure that server to only use the address you want.

If that server/service cannot be configured as required you can use firewall filtering (iptables) to restrict connectivity.